# Program do not crash on heap overflow

Tags: c, malloc, heap-corruption

I have written following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *input;
  input = (char*)malloc(16);
  printf("input is : %s\n", input);
}
```

When I run this as:

```
./test `python -c 'print "A"*5000'`
```

it does not crash. It rather prints data.

When I use `free(input)` after `printf`, it crashes.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because its _undefined behavior_.

Comment: is there a reliable way to create crash without having free()

Comment: The behavior you're describing doesn't make sense. Are you sure this is the _exact_ code you're running?

Comment: Use a memory checker such as valgrind to find this kind of bugs.

Comment: I am writing a test program for my assignment. This is exact  piece of code I am using to demonstrate.

Comment: Don't change the question substantively after you've been given answers.  If you feel you must edit the question, add a second version of the program with a suitable comment such as — "Oops: I missed a `strcpy()` operation.  The code really looks like this."  But it is best to get the code in the question correct before asking.  Missing out crucial lines smacks of carelessness.

Comment: Always copy/paste the code you actually tested.  Anything else is a waste of everyone's time and effort.

Answer (score 3):

The code shown ignores its command line arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *input;
  input = (char*)malloc(16);
  printf("input is : %s\n", input);
}
```

It shouldn't matter what the Python script provides.  However, your `printf()` is printing uninitialized data; that leads to undefined behaviour.  If the `printf()` doesn't crash and there is a `free(input);` call after the `printf()`, then the `free()` shouldn't crash.

If you missed out a copy operation and intended to show something like this, then the rules are different:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *input;
  input = (char*)malloc(16);
  strcpy(input, argv[1]);
  printf("input is : %s\n", input);
  free(input);
  return 0;
}
```

Now you are not checking that `argv[1]` is not a null pointer before you use it — that could cause a crash.  And you are trampling way out of bounds of the allocated memory if you pass 5000 characters in `argv[1]`.  Something will probably trigger a crash; it isn't defined what will cause the crash.  The `strcpy()` may fail; the `printf()` probably won't fail if the copy doesn't (but that isn't guaranteed); the `free()` will probably fail because you trampled out of bounds (but even that isn't guaranteed).  Such are the wonders of 'undefined behaviour'; anything could happen and it is valid behaviour.

Comment: I added strcpy now.

Comment: Don't change the question substantively after you've gotten answers diagnosing problems in the question.  That isn't fair.  It _is_ why I included a version of your original code in my answer — I had a strong suspicion the question would morph after a diagnosis was given.  I changed your `void` return type to `int` because that's what the standard expects — only Microsoft C allows `void main()`.  Assuming C99 or later, the missing return isn't a problem; there's an 'implicit `return 0;`' at the end of `main()` if there is no return at the end (but only `main()` gets this special treatment).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Clairvoyance, a useful skill. :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _there's an 'implicit return 0;' at the end of main() if there is no return at the end (but only main() gets this special treatment)_ Only `main()`? I just tried a program on gcc with -std=c99 for a function whose return type wasn't given and it returned zero anyway. I got warnings but no errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @J...S: random chance; undefined behaviour is allowed to produce the answer you expect, even if your expectations are wrong in general.  Yes, there is a specific rule for `main()`: §5.1.2.2.3 **Program termination** _If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
returned by the `main` function as its argument;11) reaching the `}` that terminates the
`main` function returns a value of `0`.…_

Comment: @J...S: Otherwise, §6.9.1 ¶12 applies: _If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
the caller, the behavior is undefined._

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this happen?

Buffer overflow (in this case [heap overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow)) doesn't cause immediately crash. Writing outside of bounds of allocated memory causes [undefined behavior](https://www.google.cz/search?q=undefined%20behavior%20c&oq=undefined%20be&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i57j69i59j0l2.1833j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - anything might happen; even it can work correctly.

> Is there a reliable way to create crash without having free()

If you don't even initialize pointer `input` and dereference it (read or write there), *most likely* you will get a SEGFAULT, but it's still 'only' undefined behavior.

From [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> **Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely with unpredictable results**, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message).

---

But be *be careful*

An overflow may result in data corruption or unexpected behavior by **any process which uses the affected memory area**. On operating systems without memory protection, this could be any process on the **system**.

Comment: It was obvious :-)